# How can I get backtrace of the running process stack by other process in mips?

Tags: c, linux, gdb, stack-trace, ptrace

I want to get backtrace of the stack in process A by process B
I know I can use `gdb --pid pid_of_A` , then use `info stack` to get backtrace of the stack in process A.

But, I want to implement it by code, not use gdb. I read gdb source code to understand how gdb do it, but gdb is to complex to understand.

Can you help to do it ?

Comment: `ptrace()` can be used for this purpose. http://linux.die.net/man/2/ptrace

Comment: For this, ptrace can only get registers，can't get backtrace. I tried failed

Comment: Check out [libunwind](http://www.nongnu.org/libunwind/).

Answer (score 0):

You should use [libgdb](http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/papers/libgdb/libgdb.html).  With *libgdb* you can programmatically execute gdb commands just like someone doing an interactive gdb session.

Here is the main function to use:

```
struct gdb_str_output gdb_execute_for_strings (char *cmd)
```

This executes the command in `cmd` (e.g. `backtrace`) and returns a structure containing the output of the command.

Comment: Can you give me a simple complete example, Thanks

Comment: `libgdb` is an aborted attempt from 1993. It was tried again in 1999 as `libgdb2`, but didn't get much traction either. https://sourceware.org/ml/gdb-patches/2009-03/msg00676.html